# Конфликт двух swiper js

Tags: javascript, swiper, swiper.js

У меня на странице есть 2 вкладки, в каждой из которой по 2 слайдера.

В первой вкладке активный thumbnail показывается первым, а во второй вкладке thumbnail показывается вторым по счету, что является проблемой

Ссылка на пример проблемы: http://roman.novgodent.beget.tech/

Фото 1 вкладки (тут все хорошо):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото 2 вкладки (тут проблема):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также прикладываю код страницы
Спасибо за помощь!

```js
var videva = new Swiper(".videva", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});

var videva2 = new Swiper(".videva2", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: videva,
  },
});

var fota = new Swiper(".fota", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});

var fota2 = new Swiper(".fota2", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: fota,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.fota2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fota {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.fota .swiper-slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.fota .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.videva2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.videva {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.videva .swiper-slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.videva .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://novgodent.pro/bitrix/templates/nd-3.0/js/swiper-bundle.min-2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://novgodent.pro/bitrix/templates/nd-3.0/css/swiper-bundle.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="photo-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#photo-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="photo-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Фото</button>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="video-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#video-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="video-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Видео </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content" id="">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="photo-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="photo-tab" tabindex="0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper fota2">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          </div>
          
          <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper fota">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="video-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="video-tab" tabindex="0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper videva2">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          </div>
          <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper videva">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поправьте стили нажав на кнопку "Править", а потом в конце на "редактировать пример кода". После этого убедитесь что ошибка воспроизводится

Comment: @EzioMercer поправил, подключил стили bootstrap и swiper
Но ошибка сохраняется

Comment: В videva у вас незакомментировано - loop: true; и фото у вас останавливается, а видева по кругу ходит

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи комментирование убрал, но все же проблема остается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю, как я решил эту проблему:

Просто добавил в параметры слайдеров `rewind: true`